# How to split up elements of a list that occupy the same index position?

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension, element

I am new to Python and can not seem to find a solution to what I am sure is a simple problem. I have a list of three elements but they occupy a single position. How can I split them up to store them in separate positions in a list?

Code:

```
li = [(2,3,6)]
```

Currently output

```
 li[0] = (2,3,6)
```

My desired output would be

```
li = [2,3,6]
```

So that `li[0] = 2, li[1] = 3, li[2] = 6`

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: li = list(li[0]) or li = [*li[0]]

Comment: That was much simpler than I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can just convert the li[0] elements to list store them in separate variables. Or save it to the same one.

For ex:-

```
li = [(1,2,3)]

li = list(li[0])

print(li)
```

output

```
Output:
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of three elements but they occupy a single position

Actually, here

```
li = [(2,3,6)]
```

`li` is not "a list of three elements", it's "a list of a single element", which single element is a `tuple` of three elements.

If you want to make a list of three elements from this, you have to

1/ extract the tuple from the list. It's the first element so it's at index zero:

```
elem = li[0]
```

2/ build a list from `elem`:

```
li = list(elem)
```

or, in a single statement:

```
li = list(li[0])
```